# Upload files to a cloud storage folder using its shared link

Tags: google-drive-api, dropbox-api, cloud-storage

Is it possible to upload files to a cloud storage folder for which I have only the shared link with edit permissions? I want to do this from my application, from code, so I'm interested in an API. I've looked into SkyDrive, GoogleDrive and DropBox APIs but I can't find a solution for this scenario in the API references.

It's fine if I have to sign in through the API with a user account to be able to upload the files to the shared link but I need to allow any user that has the link to upload files to that location.

Have I missed anything in the above mentioned APIs or are there any other cloud storage services which supply a solution for my needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

These are the steps I just took to verify.

1. User-A creates a folder called 'shared folder'
2. User-A makes that folder publicly writeable
3. User-A passes the shared URL to User-B. The key part of the URL is the id=1bxxxxxxx
4. User-B goes to https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert#try-it
5. ... where he authenticates himself
6. ... creates a request body containing **parent: "id_from_step_3"**
7. ... Executes the upload

The result is that User-B has created a file in the folder 'shared folder'

Comment: Thanks, can you add to the answer how to get the shared URL using the drive API? In any language you prefer :)

Comment: You need the folder ID, *not* the shared URL. It so happens that the URL contains the ID, but that could change. You can get the ID of a folder by opening it in the Drive Web App and looking at the URL.

Comment: How does Google prevent misuse of a publically writable folder? If I can access it via a URL, can't i just visit the URL and dump a bunch of files into that folder? And what's stopping me from writing script in the console that creates a massive blob and uploads it, thereby flooding the folder?

Comment: Nevermind, every document added to a publicly shared folder counts against the owner's limit, so there's no chance of misuse, since the folder can be flooded with bogus docs, but if they don't fit a particular structure or schema set out by the app, they're useless and there seems no point in someone doing this, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have got your self in a tangle.

**Through a shared URL**
When someone gives you a URL to view and indeed edit a file that is purely for that file. You can't therefore upload files that way. You can share folders however very easily. https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494822?hl=en https://www.dropbox.com/help/19/en

As for the API directly I can't really help you I am affraid